# Website hosted on GoDaddy returns error "Website took too long to respond"

Tags: website, web-hosting

I have a website hosted on Godaddy with a dedicated server. It sometimes loads fine but sometimes it results in the error that the "Website took too long to respond". Any ideas on the reason this could be happening? The website is not too loaded, averaging around a 1000 users a day.

Comment: What did godaddy say when you asked them?

Comment: They aren't helpful. Just wanted to check if there were any obvious reasons for this.

Comment: You still didn’t answer my question.

Comment: *Any ideas on the reason this could be happening?* -- The server, or the connection to the server, is slow or failing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try few points:

- Check your internet connection.
- Check whether your website is down. If the server is having issues, there is nothing you can do but wait it out, fortunately, most sites won't be down for long once the server owners see the problem.
- Clear server cache if you have enabled it, some servers support varnish cache; disable it
- Remove all cache from your browser